# ReactiveUI Xamarin-Android - ReactiveListAdapter performance issue

Tags: c#, performance, xamarin, xamarin.android, reactiveui

I've recently started to use [ReactiveUI](http://reactiveui.net/) for my Xamarin-Android and -iOS projects. It works pretty well regarding to separation of concerns etc and I like it really much but unfortunately I've discovered a performance issue when using the `ReactiveListAdapter`. It seems like the more bindings I add (e.g. `this.WhenAnyValue(..)` or `this.OneWayBind(..)`) the more jerky the list is getting.

This is how it looks like on a Samsung Nexus 10 with android version 5.1.1:

[image]
(I used a GridView instead of a ListView because it shows the jerkiness a bit better)

I've created a really simple [sample application](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Xamarin-RxUI-Performance-Test) to show how I've implemented the `ReactiveListAdapter`. Am I doing something wrong here or is there a better way to implement that with the ReactiveListAdapter? Thanks